# Dust went into my MacBook left speaker

Tags: macbook-pro, speakers

So last night when I finished using my MacBook and then I noticed the left speaker had some small ball of dust. So I thought of taking it out in the morning tomorrow. So then when I tried to take it out it instead it went inside I tried gently shaking the MacBook to make the small dust particle to come out through the speaker. But no luck/ Should I worry about my speaker getting damaged or dust flying into the logic board and making my MacBook slow. As dust is a poor conductor of electricity.

PS. Can I just set my MacBook fan speed to 6000RPM to kick out the dust?

Comment: I don't think the fans blow air out of the speakers... Perhaps a gentle vacuuming may be sufficient.

Comment: @Solar Mike I don't think the dust is much if a big deal as it may automatically come out one day or another. So i don't think I am going to remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Because* dust doesn't conduct well, you should not worry about anything getting damaged, especially not if it's small enough to fit through the speaker.

Fact is that a lot of dust slows down electronics, but such small quantities, as said, shouldn't be a problem.

*If* you still want to get it out, you should probably do as Solar Mike said and just vacuum it a little.